# How do you count all users in all guilds in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to count how many users are in all of the guilds my discord.js bot is in, but the only help I can find is v12 based and does not work in v13. My code and error message is below. How do I upgrade it to v13?

> ```
>   throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
>         ^
> ```

> DiscordAPIError: 404: Not Found

```
client.users.fetch()
const users = client.users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot);
console.log(users.size);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) is a manager for **all** Discord users, which is why you can't just cache all. The way you see how many users the bot is in is by looping through the guilds and adding the member count. Use [`Collection#reduce()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=reduce) for this

```js
const userCount = client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) => a+g.memberCount, 0)
```

However, there is no way to filter out all users by bots unless you are using GuildMembers

Comment: I am getting the error "throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request); DiscordAPIError: 404: Not Found" when I do "interaction.client.users.fetch()  
   const userCount = interaction.client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) => a+g, 0)  
   console.log(userCount.size);

Comment: @TGercken remove the `client.users.fetch()`. Read the first sentence of this answer

Comment: I removed it and am getting the same answer. Are you saying that the code you provided does the loop or do you need a separate loop to cache server users?

Comment: Actually now I'm getting undefined so maybe that's some progress

Comment: The solution appears to be "interaction.client.guilds.cache.reduce((acc, guild) => acc + guild.memberCount, 0)"

Comment: This code itself does the loop

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer is:

> interaction.client.guilds.cache.reduce((acc, guild) => acc + guild.memberCount, 0)